# Firebase Android - query addChildEventListener crashes from array index out of bounds?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to use Firebase with my Android app, and I'm trying to call the addChildEventListener to a database reference. However this reference may be empty initially (created but no child within it), which Firebase doesn't seem to check and I get an invalid index 0, size is 0 error and my app crashes.

```
query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: It was a bug on my part! The string variable i was using to reference the node was just null in some cases :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FireBase returns dataSnapshot as null if it does not find any data with respect to particular node or if the node does not exist. So that is a normal behaviour only.
PS: the above case is true in case of

```
 addValueEventListener and addListenerForSingleValueEvent
```

but in case of addChildEvent listener I don't thing that even onChild added callback  should come.
Please paste more code

Comment: But why should it crash if I don't call anything inside the override methods? So if I have a node that is created by a user and filled with data on user actions, and I need to be listening for it to update a view with its data, how would I do that? Right now I'm doing so by creating a dummy child when the node is first created, but not sure if that's the right way.

Comment: Oops never I mind. I just realized the error was being caused not by Firebase but the String variable that I was using to retrieve the node, which was null for some other issue. I'll fix this and let you know if everything works as expected!

Comment: Yea seems like that was just it. Things are working as expected now although onChildAdded is being called twice when there's only one child. Any idea why? Also why is it that Firebase combines the query with these on event listeners? I feel it would make more sense if they had a separate query feature and used these to attach listeners for the database. (seems confusing to use onChildAdded event listener to get existing children from the database)

Comment: it is very likely that you are  are adding the onChildChanged Listener multiple times. ie you are not removing the previous listener in ondestroy /on pause of your fragment / activity. Besides query is combined with event listeners to provide asynchronous and non-UI blocking feature.

Comment: i do create the listener just once in onResume and destroy it onPause. Shouldn't be the issue...

Comment: well i'll create another thread for this if i cant fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I can't figure out why that might be happening. Please let me know also if you get the answer to that.

Comment: Haven't figured it out but using ValueEventLister and going through the children of the DataSnapshot works fine. It seems like a bug with child_Added since the two should essentially do the same thing.